# PDF of sufficient statistic of a normal distribution $N(0, \theta)$

Tags: probability, statistical-inference

Given:

$x_1, x_2....x_n$ is a random sample and an iid with normal distribution $N(0,\theta)$ where variance is the unknown paramter.

I calculated the sufficient statistic for this case and it comes out to be:
$$Y = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2$$

Now, I want to find the pdf of this Sufficient statistic Y and the distribution of Y?

I know $Y/\theta$ is equal to $Y = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2/\theta$ is a chi-square of distribution with n degrees of freedom. How can I get the pdf:

1. Using the change of variables
2. Using moment generating function (MGF)

Can anyone help me know how to do this? What are the steps? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First observe that $\frac{X}{\sqrt{\theta}}\sim N(0;1)$ and thus

$$ \bbox[5px,border:2px solid black]
{
\frac{X^2}{\theta}\sim \chi_{(1)}^2=Gamma\Big(\frac{1}{2};\frac{1}{2}\Big)
\qquad (1) 
}
$$

Now it is evident that

$$ \bbox[5px,border:2px solid black]
{
T=\frac{1}{\theta}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i^2\sim Gamma\Big(\frac{n}{2};\frac{1}{2}\Big)
\qquad (2) 
}
$$

Concluding, $Y=\theta T$,

thus

$$ \bbox[5px,border:2px solid black]
{
Y\sim Gamma\Big(\frac{n}{2};\frac{1}{2\theta}\Big)
\qquad (3) 
}
$$

---

To prove (1) and (3) use the fundamental transformation theorem (change of variable)

To prove (2) use MGF's properties

---

**Some hints for the proofs:**

For (1), use the change of variable

$Z=\frac{X^2}{\theta}$ then

$$F_Z(z)=\mathbb{P}[Z\leq z]=\mathbb{P}[X^2\leq z\theta]=\mathbb{P}[-\sqrt{z\theta}\leq X \leq \sqrt{z\theta}]=F_X(\sqrt{z\theta})-F_X(-\sqrt{z\theta})$$

derivate it and get you first PDF:

$$f_Z(z)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}z^{-\frac{1}{2}}e^{-\frac{z}{2}}$$

This can be rewritten in the following way:

$$f_Z(z)=\frac{\Big(\frac{1}{2}\Big)^{\frac{1}{2}}}{\Gamma\Big(\frac{1}{2}\Big)}z^{\frac{1}{2}-1}e^{-\frac{z}{2}}$$

...and the first step is done! $f(z)$ is evidently a $Gamma\Big(\frac{1}{2};\frac{1}{2}\Big)$

For step (2) very easily multiply the n identical MGF's

For step (3) same procedure as (1): change of variable.

Comment: Thanks, Tommik. This is a nice way to explain. Makes it more clear now. I am not sure how to use them to get the PDF then using two different methods. I have to basically find the pdf of sum of chi-square by change or variables and MGF. Correct?

Comment: @tanaymukherjee : I edited the answer with some hints: it is very easy, if you are stuck somewhere let me know. Everything can be easy proved. The most "difficult" is (1). The rest is very trivial to prove

Comment: @tanaymukherjee : proving (2) with change of variable is not an easy work. You can use the 2 methods in the following way: Change of variable for (1) , (3) and MGF for (2). Since you're new here, I would like to encourage you to click the check mark if this answer was helpful for you. It'll encourage others to answer your questions in the future

Comment: I am trying, but I really don't know. I knew by additive property that the sum will be a chi - square. With your logic I can see what the pdf would look like if I consider (3) as is. But, how to get there. Uh, not sure.

Comment: @tanaymukherjee :added some further hints, I hope this help

Comment: Thanks for the directions. Yes, I was able to finish this using change of variables, and I get the equation (3). From there I just replaced the value to get pdf for Y in the question. For MGF I have the product of n individual moments for chi-square. From there, I don't know. I know how to get MGF from pdfs, but this reverse tracking is confusing.

Comment: One question @tommik actually I was about to put a new question then I found this question. My question is ...Is $\sum_{i}X_i$ are sufficient statistic as well? I said this because $-\infty<x<\infty$ in the normal distribution and taking square root of our sufficient statistic is not a one-to-one transformation therefore not a sufficient statistic. Am I right?

Comment: @Daman : Yes, You are right.